# How to turn on speaker programmatically in android

Tags: android

How to turn on speaker programmatically when incoming calls received and headphone attached on audio jack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)
```

Be sure to include the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission in your manifest.

Comment: Does this line make speaker phone on when headphone attached?

Answer (score 2):

```
// for android 10 and higher
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_START_CALL_WITH_SPEAKERPHONE, true);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
```

Comment: Hi Elad D, Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for helping our friend, when possible, try adding more information about the solution, on how you came up with it, and where we can learn more about it

Comment: Hi Elad,thank you very much,your solution worked for me . my device is Xiaomi Remi Note7 with  Android 9.